# How to have scrolling in Java GUI JTextArea with Eclipse?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I am trying to put an muti lines text in the `JtextArea`, but there isn't a scrolling so I cannot move to see any data below the default `JtextArea` area, here is the code and `textArea_1` is the `JtextArea`:

```
String abc="";
for(int i=0; i<=100; i++){
abc = abc + data[i][0]+"\n";
}
textArea_1.setText(abc);
```

Comment: show a SSCCE - the solution provided in the answers typically _does_ work, so you are doing something wrong elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

You need to look into adding a `JScrollPane`.

Link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html

```
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(TEXTAREAHERE);
```

Comment: Every line is just few numbers for my case, does that affect anything?

Comment: @macaugmxus Please show us how you are trying to add the `JScrollPane` to your code so that we may help fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Scrolling is handled by `JScrollPane`.

Check out [How to use scroll panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) and for your own reference, [`JScrollPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html) and which is also demonstrated in [How to use Text Areas](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textarea.html)

**Updated with example**

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestScrollPane04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScrollPane04();
    }

    public TestScrollPane04() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 20);
                String abc = "";
                for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
                    abc = abc + "This is some additional text " + i + "\n";
                }
                textArea.setText(abc);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(textArea));
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: @macaugmxus Works perfectly fine for me

Comment: I see my code has contentPane.add(textArea_1); I use the windowsbuilder to make the gui so it looks kind of different from your example...

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `JScrollPane`. as

```
JscrollPane myScroll=new JScrollPane(textArea_1);
```

If your text is more than that can see other text by scrolling. By default when you `set` or `append` text to `JTextArea` it scrolls to end (you can see that if text is large so that scroll bar appeard). So to scroll back to first line try

```
textArea_1.setCaretPosition(0);
```

see [Java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#setCaretPosition%28int%29)